# Data not getting returned from snowflake using DBeaver

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

I am connecting DBeaver to snowflake using jdbc 3.13.5 driver.When I am running queries on snowflake, the queries are not returning any data and are getting stuck in Discover attributes. When I check it on Snowflake history, the query already ran.
So in conclusion , the query ran on snowflake, but not able to display result in DBeaver.

Please help.

Comment: Do you have the same issue from SnowSQL, Python, or the UI?

Comment: Nope there are no issues with Snowsql, python or UI. Just with DBeaver. Weird thing is it was working good for like 3 -4 months and suddenly , its not getting any data

Comment: Using the same Snowflake role that your DBeaver connection is using, can you run the query in the Snowflake WebUI?

Comment: Are you on the current version of DBeaver?

Comment: Yup the role is the same when I am running the query on DBeaver and snowflake. The DBeaver version is 7.3.3.202101161839

Comment: Disconnect the DB from DBeaver and then reconnect and reinitialize it and then test if the issue still persists.
And is this DBeaver Community edition?

Comment: Yup, I did it already and its not working. Yup, I have community edition

Comment: I am using free trial community edition and having the same issue there too

Comment: Can you add the screenshot for the connection settings for SF from DBeaver ?

Comment: Sure here is the screenshot

Comment: https://github.com/navrah2008/Tutorial/blob/main/dbeaver-snowflake-connection.png

Comment: Does the same work with public url?